# Automate a Ruby Gem install that has input

Tags: ruby, database, automation, rubygems, db2

I am trying to install the ibm_db gem so that I can access DB2 from Ruby.  When I try:

```
sudo gem install ibm_db
```

I get the following request for clarification:

```
Select which gem to install for your platform (i486-linux)
 1. ibm_db 0.10.0 (ruby)
 2. ibm_db 0.10.0 (mswin32)
 3. ibm_db 0.9.5 (mswin32)
 4. ibm_db 0.9.5 (ruby)
 5. Skip this gem
 6. Cancel installation
```

I am always going to be installing the linux version (which I assume is the "ruby" version), so is there a way to pick which one I will install straight from the gem install command?

The reason this is a problem is that I need to automate this install via a bash script, so I would like to select that I want the "ruby" version ahead of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a 'here document'. That is:

```
sudo gem install ibm_db <<heredoc
  1
heredoc
```

What's between the \<\<\SOMETHING and SOMETHING gets inputted as entry to the previous command (somewhat like ruby's own heredocuments). The 1 there alone, of course, is the selection of the "ibm_db 0.10.0 (ruby)" platform.

Hope it's enough.

Comment: This is the solution that works for rubygems version 0.9.4... check your gems help install to see if there is a --platform option.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sudo gem install --platform ruby ibm_db
```

Note that you can get help on the install command using:

```
gem help install
```

---

**UPDATE:** Looks like this option only works for RubyGems 0.9.5 or above.

Comment: Clarification: It doesn't work on Ubuntu which uses 0.9.4 rubygems (in the repos), but it appears this may be a feature of later versions of rubygems.

Answer (score 0):

@[John Topley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103918/automate-a-ruby-gem-install-that-has-input#104102)

I already tried gem help install, and --platform is not an option, both in help and in practice:

```
$ sudo gem install ibm_db --platform ruby
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
    invalid option: --platform
```

---

**UPDATE**: The Ubuntu repos have 0.9.4 version of rubygems, which doesn't have the --platform option.  It appears it may be [a new feature in 0.9.5](http://rubyforge.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=23112), but there is still no online documentation for it, and regardless, it won't work on Ubuntu which is the platform I need it to work on.

Comment: Which version of RubyGems are you on? I just tried it on Mac OS X using RubyGems v1.2.0 and didn't get that error.

Comment: The newest version installed from apt-get install rubygems on Ubuntu... also see: http://www.rubygems.org/read/chapter/10#page33 (No --platform specified in the rubygems online documentation)

Comment: What's the output from gem -v
?

Comment: 0.9.4, which is what ubuntu repositories have... regardless the rubygems website itself doesn't list your option...

Comment: It appears to be in the next version beyond what Ubuntu repos have

Comment: Online documentation may not always be up to date. You can update RubyGems itself to the latest version using sudo gem update --system

Comment: I prefer to let my packaging system (apt-get) deal with the updates, but thanks ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I think it only works on Bash though

```
sudo gem install ibm_db < <(echo 1)
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting... though piping echo output may work as well...? IE sudo gem install ibm_db | echo "1"

Answer (score 0):

Versions of Rubygems from 1.0 and up automatically detect the platform you are running and thus do not ask that question. Are you able to update your gems to the latest?

```
$ sudo gem update --system
```

Be warned if you are on Windows once you have updated; you might run into [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43778/sqlite3-ruby-gem-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension).

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer to use my packaging system to update my applications (ie, apt-get since I am on Ubuntu) :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to download the .gem file and install it manually as such:

```
sudo gem install path/to/ibm_db-0.10.0.gem
```

This particular gem was at [rubyforge](http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=2361&release_id=25677).