# Gem update on Windows - is it broken?

Tags: windows, ruby, rubygems

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43778/sqlite3-ruby-gem-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension).

When I issue the **`gem update`** command on Windows, whenever it gets to a
gem whose latest version DOESN'T have Windows binaries, it'll attempt to
build the native extension which will, of course, fail. For example:

```
Updating sqlite3-ruby
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)
  ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

c:/ruby/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb update
checking for fdatasync() in rt.lib... no
checking for sqlite3.h... no

nmake
'nmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

The old pre-1.x behavior of asking for the required platform at least
made updating possible. Now I can't update at all unless I uninstall the
troublesome gems (currently sqlite3-ruby and hpricot), run the update,
then re-install the gems using the --version switch.

Does anyone have a solution to this conundrum or are we stuck with it?

---

**Note:**

```
$ gem -v
1.2.0

$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.6 (2007-09-24 patchlevel 111) [i386-mswin32]
```

---

**Note (26 September 2008):** I just updated to gems 1.3.0 and this problem persists.

**Note (18 November 2008):** Just updated to gems 1.3.1 and the problem persists.

**Note (28 April 2009):** The latest version of Gems ([1.3.2](http://blog.segment7.net/articles/2009/04/15/rubygems-1-3-2)) now skips any gems where building of native extensions fails during update; in other words, the problem is fixed. Hooray!

Comment: Do you mean 28 April 2009? Or are you after the time traveller badge?

Comment: What if I want to install a new gem and it fails when installing? Gems 1.3.2 has this solved??

Comment: Yes, this problem has long since been fixed. As of today, we're now at RubyGems version 1.3.7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gems, as of [version 1.3.2](http://blog.segment7.net/articles/2009/04/15/rubygems-1-3-2), will now skip gems that fail to build, so update Rubygems to the latest version and the problem discussed here should be solved.

```
gem update --system
```

***The following solution is now deprecated, but I leave it here for the record.***

I [started a thread on this issue](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/166693) on the Ruby Forum (it's a front end to the mailing list). There's some interesting discussion; it's worth a read. There's even a very hacky solution to this problem on there:

```
`gem.bat outdated`.split(/\n/).map{|z|z.scan(/^[^[:space:]]+/)}.flatten.each{|z| `gem.bat update #{z}`}
```

It calls the `gem outdated` command and builds a list of all of the outdated gems. It then iterates over the list and calls `gem update` for each individual outdated gem. If one fails, it just moves onto the next.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that we are stuck. I have found [here](http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=254) that there is no mswin32 gem for the last version (1.2.4), I tried to install it on my computer and got the same problem.

Installing the previous version works fine:

```
gem install sqlite3-ruby --version '1.2.3'
```

Comment: Yes, that does work and it's what I've done. The problem is then when you subsequently run gem update; it automatically tries to update to 1.2.4.

Answer (score 2):

Execute the below command and it should work:

```
gem install sqlite3-ruby --platform=mswin32
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [RubyForge file list](http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=254) for sqlite3-ruby reveals that version 1.2.3 has gems that were built using Visual Studio 6 and MinGW (sqlite3-ruby-1.2.3-mswin32.gem & sqlite3-ruby-1.2.3-x86-mingw32.gem). However, version 1.2.4 doesn't not have any such pre-built gems.

If you have Visual Studio 6 or [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) installed and have the compiler environment variables set up (at least for Visual Studio 6 but not sure about MinGW), the gem should build during installation. I'm not sure if the gems will build under newer versions of Visual Studio.