# Installing starling on Windows

Tags: ruby, rubygems, starling-server

I am trying to install the starling gem on my Windows machine.  But, whenever I try to install it I get this error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...  
ERROR:  Error installing starling:  
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.  

c:/ruby/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb install starling -- --srcdir= c:\ruby-1.8.7-p72  
checking for windows.h... no  
*** extconf.rb failed ***  
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:  
        --with-opt-dir  
        --without-opt-dir  
        --with-opt-include  
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include  
        --with-opt-lib  
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib  
        --with-make-prog  
        --srcdir=.  
        --curdir  
        --ruby=c:/ruby/bin/ruby  

Gem files will remain installed in c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/eventmachine-0
.12.2 for inspection.  
Results logged to c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/eventmachine-0.12.2/ext/gem_mak
e.out
```

What do I need to install to provide the `windows.h` header?

Answer (score 6):

Gems <strike>is [somewhat broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134581/gem-update-on-windows-is-it-broken) on Windows at present</strike> was at the time broken on Windows, but it's fixed now. The following workaround applies to the old One-Click Installer version of Ruby; you should really update to the new MinGW-based [RubyInstaller](http://rubyinstaller.org/) and the [DevKit](http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit/) to which the workaround still works, but is more future proof.

- Locate a version of the problem gem (in this case it's **eventmachine**) that has a win32 binary. If you look on [RubyForge](http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=1555), you'll see that the last eventmachine gem to possess a win32 binary is version 0.12.0
- Force that version of event machine to install:

  `$ gem install eventmachine --version=0.12.0

  Successfully installed eventmachine-0.12.0-x86-mswin32

  1 gem installed

  Installing ri documentation for eventmachine-0.12.0-x86-mswin32...

  Installing RDoc documentation for eventmachine-0.12.0-x86-mswin32...`
- Now install try installing your original gem again:

  `$ gem install starling

  Successfully installed ZenTest-3.10.0

  Successfully installed memcache-client-1.5.0

  Successfully installed SyslogLogger-1.4.0

  Successfully installed starling-0.9.8

  4 gems installed

  Installing ri documentation for ZenTest-3.10.0...

  Installing ri documentation for memcache-client-1.5.0...

  Installing ri documentation for SyslogLogger-1.4.0...

  Installing ri documentation for starling-0.9.8...

  Installing RDoc documentation for ZenTest-3.10.0...

  Installing RDoc documentation for memcache-client-1.5.0...

  Installing RDoc documentation for SyslogLogger-1.4.0...

  Installing RDoc documentation for starling-0.9.8...`

Be warned though, if you now run **`gem update`** gems will stupidly try and install the latest version of eventmachine which, as we already know, won't build on Windows. This causes gem update to stop completely. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134581/gem-update-on-windows-is-it-broken) to find out how to work around *this* particular annoyance.

Answer (score 0):

The install seems to be stuck on installing the eventmachine gem.
The easiest approach here may be to download and install the eventmachine binary gem for windows [here](http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=1555&release_id=22647)

Otherwise you will need a compiler. (which I assume you don't have)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work but someone is working on a one click installer of Ruby under Windows that comes with a C compiler.

See http://github.com/luislavena/rubyinstaller/tree/master

Answer (score 0):

Now that everything is installed, is it possible to get it working under windows?  I'm getting a fork() function unimplemented on this machine, because, Windows doesn't have a fork() process.