# Ruby on Rails gem problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm using Ruby on rails (RubyMine) and I try starting my project.
Which tells me the error "Could not find gem 'mysql2 (~> 0.2.6, runtime)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile. (Bundler::GemNotFound)".

I've done sudo gem install mysql which gives me

"Error installing mysql:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/ext/mysql_api/gem_make.out
"

What should I do?

Comment: You're probably missing a dependency to build mysql.  Open `/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/ext/mysql_api/gem_make.out` and see what failed.

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43778/sqlite3-ruby-gem-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably missing the development headers for MySQL. Often this is shipped as an optional package to install. You may need to install `mysql-dev` or `mysql-devel` depending on your package manager.

You might also be missing a compiler, so check that you have the required dependencies for `gem` such as `make` and `gcc`.

Comment: You probably need to install a bunch of things with `apt-get` then, starting with `gcc`. If you use the graphical installer, you'll need to add the "Development Tools". This might get you one step closer: `apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev`

Comment: Thank you, @tadman. Your comment worked for me on Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the Ruby development headers as well. On my Ubuntu 11.04 box I have the following aptitude package which is needed for native gem compilation:

`ruby1.9.1-dev`