# I am unable to install sqlite3 on rails 3.2 Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

Here is my error:
C:>gem install sqlite3-ruby
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3-ruby:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
```

checking for sqlite3.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby
        --with-sqlite3-dir
        --without-sqlite3-dir
        --with-sqlite3-include
        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
        --with-sqlite3-lib
        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/
        --enable-local
        --disable-local
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:431:in `try_do': The compiler failed to ge
nerate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:562:in`try_cpp'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:1086:in `block in find_header
'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:892:in`block in checking_for
'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:337:in `block (2 levels) in p
ostpone'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:307:in`open'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:337:in `block in postpone'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:307:in`open'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:333:in `postpone'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:891:in`checking_for'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:1085:in `find_header'
        from extconf.rb:34:in`'

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sqlit
e3-1.3.7 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/ext/sqli
te3/gem_make.out

Gemfile:
         source 'https://rubygems.org'

```
     gem 'rails'
     gem 'jquery-rails'
     gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.0.0'
     gem 'bcrypt-ruby'
     gem 'faker', '1.0.1'
     gem 'will_paginate'
     gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.5'

     group :development, :test do
     gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
     gem 'rspec-rails', '2.12.2'
     gem 'guard-rspec', '0.5.5'
    end

    # Gems used only for assets and not required
    # in production environments by default.
    group :assets do
      gem 'sass-rails', '3.2.4'
      gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
      gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
    end

    group :test do
       gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
       gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.4.0'
        gem 'cucumber-rails', '1.2.1', require: false
       gem 'database_cleaner', '0.7.0'
       gem 'rb-fsevent', '0.4.3.1', :require => false
        gem 'growl', '1.0.3'
       gem 'guard-spork', '0.3.2'
        gem 'spork', '0.9.2'
       gem 'launchy', '2.1.0'
       gem 'ffi', '1.1.0'
     end
```

I have installed DevKit. I am running ruby 2.0.0. Everything was running perfectly on Ruby 1.9.3. Can anyone help me?

Things I have tried:

```
     1. bundle install (I do not know why it just skips sqlite3)
     2. gem install sqlite3
     3. gem install sqlite3-ruby
     4. I've also included the -- --with-sqlite3-dir=/usr/local/lib on each of those lines
```

When I do bundle install, it skips over the sqlite3 gem and installs all the other gems normally.

I've installed the devkit and I went to the sqlite3 website and got the .dll for windows and the exe file and put it in my ruby2.0 bin folder.

EDIT: Also, when I run rails server and load locahost:3000, it tells me to run gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter

When I do run this, it says there is no such gem and to include it in my gemfile, but it is included in my gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use railsinstaller  from
http://railsinstaller.org/

and reinstall your ruby and rails it will work for me

Answer (score 0):

> I think you can use railsinstaller from http://railsinstaller.org/
>
> and reinstall your ruby and rails it will work for me

but this not Ruby 2.0

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem (ABI breakage) with installing the sqlite3 gem for Ruby 2.0 on Windows. Luckily, someone made a package that lets you install sqlite3 anyway:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/rubyinstaller/gedIaMryCFQ

See also:
[Getting Ruby on Rails environment working and installing sqlite3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15574693/getting-ruby-on-rails-environment-working-and-installing-sqlite3)

Answer (score 0):

Change to rails version 3.0.9.

I only know how to change for a new app though :

```
rails _3.0.9_ new APP_NAME
```